# CodeIgniter doesn't see images (using file_exists)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm learning CodeIgniter. I have a directory `img` with images (path `/img/`). I am trying to access it through CI view and check if exists with this code:

```
    $av = '../../../img/content/users/'.$userID.'.jpg';
    if(file_exists($av)) {
        $avatar = $av;
    } else {
    $avatar = 'img/content/users/none.jpg';
    }
```

Funny thing is, echoing `<img src="'.$av.'">` works. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe try `BASEPATH.'/img/content/users/'.$userID.'.jpg'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following steps

1) Create a custom config file name site_config.php in config file (/application/config/) and paste following code

```
<?php

$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

if(!defined('DOCUMENT_ROOT')) define('DOCUMENT_ROOT',str_replace('system/application/config','',substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos(__FILE__, '/'))));

$config['base_path']    =   constant("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
?>
```

2) Edit autoload.php to autoload site_config.php (/application/config/autoload.php)

```
$autoload['config'] = array('site_config');
```

3) Then using following code to view image

```
$image_path = $this->config->item('base_path').'folder_name/'.$userID.'.jpg';
if(file_exists($image_path)) {
  $avatar = $this->config->item('base_url').'folder_name/'.$userID.'.jpg';
} else {
  $avatar = $this->config->item('base_url').'default_folder_name/profile.jpg';
}
echo '<img src="'.$avatar.'" />';
```

I think it will help you

Comment: Works only when I'm in top directory.

Comment: Gave it another spin, and it worked. I must have done some mistakes before.

Answer (score 3):

CI always runs on `index.php`, so paths are always relative from there.

Assuming `index.php` and `/img` are at the same level in the root, try this:

```
$av = 'img/content/users/'.$userID.'.jpg';
if(is_file($av)) { // or better yet, make sure it's really an image
    $avatar = $av;
} else {
    $avatar = 'img/content/users/none.jpg';
}
```

> Funny thing is, echoing `<img src="'.$av.'">` works

It's because the browser is looking in a different place than the server. I'd recommend not using `../../relative/paths` but using functions like `base_url()` and `img()`. When there are additional segments in the URL, relative paths break.

Answer (score 2):

URLs and file paths are not the same. From the current URL `../../../img/content/users` may and likely is something completely different than the file path on the hard disk where the view file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$av = './img/content/users/'.$userID.'.jpg';
```

Comment: This works only when I don't go anywhere deeper that the 1st level of link structure.

Comment: right. use Wesleys method or use `$av = base_url().'img/content/users/'.$userID.'.jpg';`

Comment: Doesn't work, `file_exists` works localy - it can't be used for files with http addresses.