# CodeIgniter gives 404 after uploading to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter installation on my local machine. I used `hosts` file in Windows and Apache config to make it work under my real domain name (eg. `site.com`). It worked great, so today I uploaded everything to my host. I changed `hosts` and Apache config, flushed DNS via `ipconfig /flushdns` and now entering certain URLs (`games`) gives me 404.

My controller name starts with uppercase but I have routes set like this:

```
$route['Games/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'Games/Game/$1';
$route['games/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'Games/Game/$1';
```

Either entering this by `games/14/game` or `Games/14/game` doesn't work.

Searching for images (using [solution given by merahulpk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100706/codeigniter-doesnt-see-images-using-file-exists))  doesn't work also.

What can it be?

Unfortunately, it's still under development, so I can't give you the aaddess just yet.

-- edit --

Image inclusion script:

`views/game.php`

```
<?php
    $image_path = $this->config->item('base_path').'images/games/'.$info['id'].'-s.jpg';
    if(file_exists($image_path)) {
        $small = $this->config->item('base_url').'images/games/'.$info['id'].'-s.jpg';
        $big = $this->config->item('base_url').'images/games/'.$info['id'].'-b.jpg';
    } else {
        $small = $this->config->item('base_url').'images/games/none-m.png';
        $big = $this->config->item('base_url').'images/games/none-m.png';
    }
?>
```

`config/sit-config.php`

```
<?php

$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

if(!defined('DOCUMENT_ROOT')) define('DOCUMENT_ROOT',str_replace('system/application/config','',substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos(__FILE__, '/'))));

$config['base_path']    =   constant("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use uppercase letters in your routes. Use all lowercase like this:

```
$route['games/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'games/game/$1';
```

Routes won't work if you use uppercase controller name. As for method names, they can be either lowercase of uppercase, both will work... no need for duplicate routes!

Comment: Works great! Only those images aren't still visible.

Comment: is there a reason you cannot include images using absolute path? like `/images/games/image.jpg`? are you running the page from a sub-folder?

Comment: ah, I see... didn't realize that... so does `var_dump($image_path = $this->config->item('base_path'))` return what you expect? did you check its output?

Comment: It returns this: `/www/tomek_www/www/tomek/application/config`. It's config's path on server. Weird, it shoudn't return `application/config`, shodun't it?

Comment: After realising that path is weird, I changed `if(!defined('DOCUMENT_ROOT')) define('DOCUMENT_ROOT',str_replace('system/application/config','',substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos(__FILE__, '/'))));` to `if(!defined('DOCUMENT_ROOT')) define('DOCUMENT_ROOT',str_replace('application/config','',substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos(__FILE__, '/'))));` in `config/site_config.php`. and it works. Thanks a bunch Zathrus!!!